# Pushing a new view when clicking on the cell of a table view in android

Tags: android

I created a table view and display some text there with help of experts in android.

Now i wish to push a new view when user click on each cell of a table view.

I created a new class within the same package named Newview.java.

The labels are displaying correctly in three different rows.

But when i click the first cell the program is crashing.

Can you please help me where im going wrong.

```
HelloTableLayoutActivity.java

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class HelloTableLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView name =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent nameActivity =new Intent();
        nameActivity .setClass(getApplicationContext(), Newview.class);
        startActivity(nameActivity);

        }
      });
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/initial"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/hometown"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/state"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>   

</TableLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me how can i push a new view when click on the cell of table view in android.Thanks in advance.Hope for your help.

Comment: do you want to replace view being clicked with a new view, or add a new view on each click on table cell.

Comment: @jitendrasharma i just want to push a new view when a cell in the table is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your activity in the manifest like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sweans.tb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".HelloTableLayoutActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".Newview"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

To add your further activities to the manifest, add them in your `<application>` tag as shown above with the `Newview`. So, that's as far as your manifest goes. When it comes to code, there are a few things that you need to take care of.

Firstly, whenever you want to display a new screen to the user, make it a point to convert the class into an Activity. You can do it as follows:

```
public class Newview extends Activity
{
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foo);
    }
}
```

`foo` refers to an XML file name. This `foo.xml` which will be in your `res/layout/` will contain another layout to display to your user. So, when you're switching screens/activities, make sure you've your `foo.xml` filled with atleast a `TextView` so that you don't get confused as to whether your app is working or not.

One last thing. When you `extend` your class with `Activity`, make sure you `import` all related packages such as `import android.app.Activity;` for `Activity` and `import android.os.Bundle;` for `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. These are just examples.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < yourTableLayout.getChildCount; i++){
    TableRow row = (TableRow)yourTableLayout.getChildAt(i);
    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        punblic void onClick(){
            yourTableLayout.addView(new TableRow(yourActivity.this));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: what name to be given there at "yourTableLayout".My main.xml starts with "TableLayout".So whether i have to create a id named android:layout="Table" something like that

Answer (score 1):

In the activity where you are going to use the above layout try to call onClickListener for each textview and in onClickListener call another activity like

```
TextView name =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
Intent nameActivity =new Intent();
nameActivity .setClass(getApplicationContext(), nameActivity.class);
startActivity(nameActivity );
```

}

Comment: i edited my answer.can you please help me where im going wrong.